# searching for a descriptive term beyond mastery

Tags: single-word-requests

What word would be appropriate to use when describing the next level beyond mastery?

Answer (score 1):

Doyen is a word meaning "the most respected or prominent person in a particular field", that's probably the closest meaning noun there is.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/doyen

Supremacy means "being above all others in power or authority", i think you could stretch the meaning to include scientific or artistic mastery but i'm not sure.